# how to remove padding from bootstrap 4 card text?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want both bootstrap 4 cards heading text and text to start with the left line where image starts. Please have a look at the image, there is some padding around text and how I can remove it?
https://ibb.co/F4r2ZgN

Comment: Use can use utility classes , pl-0 to set the padding left to be 0 or ml-0 for margin. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thank you. Done, I placed it in wrong position before. It works with card-body!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the container where you are having your title and description apply class `px-0`.

If your title and description apply class: `mx-0 px-0` that you will be sure there is no space anymore

Comment: Thank you I will check it too. Currently adding pl-0 ml-0 with the card-body class working..

Comment: Sure. But you will have a gap at then of your container between description width block and image width.

Comment: Thank you @MaxiGui, It is giving me the perfect result -- removing spaces from both ends. I will do more study on classes. Have a nice day sir.